# Submit Search on Enter Key?

Tags: forms

What needs to be done to have this form submitted when someone hits the 'enter' key?

```
<form id="search" onsubmit="javascript:search(document.getElementById('searchText'))">
  <input type='text' id='searchText' autofocus />
  <input type='button' onclick="search(document.getElementById('searchText'))" value='Search' />
</form>
```

Comment: You need an `<input type="submit"/>` element. Not sure what you're doing with the Javascript.

Comment: Aside: why not use <input type="search"> instead of <input type="text">

Answer (score 8):

You can just use a form as below, with input type submit, which in this case, if you press enter in any input - if you had more of them - it will be a default behaviour of the form to be submitted:

```
<form id="search">
  <input type='text' id='searchText' />
  <input type='submit' value='Search' />
</form>
```

or, as it shows, you want to use the onsubmit function and handle the "submit" of the form, so you can do this:

```
<form id="search" action="#">
    <input type="text" id='searchText' name="myinput" onkeypress="handle" />
</form>

<script>
    function handle(e){
        if(e.key === "Enter"){
            alert("Enter was just pressed.");
        }

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

A code, quite the same, can be found on this similar question: [How to capture Enter key press?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987300/how-to-trigger-enter-key-press-of-textbox)

Hope I answered your question, even out of time.

Answer (score 0):

This example worked perfectly for me:

```
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");

// Execute a function when the user releases a key on the keyboard
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    // Cancel the default action, if needed
    event.preventDefault();
    // Trigger the button element with a click
    document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
  }
});
```

[I took the example at w3schools.](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_trigger_button_enter.asp)